# Realm Database Design

Tags: swift, realm

I have an example database as follows:

```
class Company:Object {
    dynamic var companyName = ""
    let employees = List<Employee>()
}

class Employee:Object {
    dynamic var companyName = "" // Is this required?
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = ""
}
```

Is the `companyName` property in class `Employee` neccessary? If not how would I reference the employees that belongs to a particular company in the query.

Comment: offtopic: It should be name instead of companyName for a good design, because you are already inside a company object and everybody knows that the attribute belongs to the company.

Comment: *Is it necessary?* You decide. *Can you need it later?* Likely. It may be useful if you thought about the design in a relational way; to know which common attributes should be shared.

Comment: @Xatenev Having the same name is better. Think of it as a foreign key.

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf how is companyName inside the Company class a foreign key? :O

Comment: @Xatenev It isn't. But if you think of the two classes as two relational tables, then it makes sense. Having `companyName` as the explicit identifier of the `Company` entity.

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf Other than using it to reference it to which company it belongs,  I don't use it anywhere. I'm asking this question because I'm do not know how to query for the employee without using the `companyName` reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linkingObjects feature of Realm for that purpose like this:

```
class Company:Object {
    dynamic var companyName = ""
    let employees = List<Employee>()
}

class Employee:Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = ""
    var company: Company? {
        return linkingObjects(Company.self, forProperty: "employees").first
    }
}
```

This approach saves you the effort to keep your Employee object's companyName property accurate and it also saves you space since company here is not stored. If you choose this path you can get your Employee's company object easily like this: (this returns nil if Employee is not associated to any Company)

```
let aCompany = someEmployee.company
```

And to answer your question

> If not how would I reference the employees that belongs to a particular company in the query.

you already have a way to do this since you store a Company's Employee's in its list `employees`, so you can just use that property like this to get Employees that belong to a company:

```
let aCompanysEmployees = someCompany.employees
```

Comment: How would I do that using the realm filter. Say I want to search for an employee with age 60 and belongs to company ABC. Cause with the `companyName` in the `employee`  class, I will do something like `filter("companyName = 'ABC' and age = 60")`

Comment: If I were you I would set `companyName` as primary key for your `Company` model and then do something like this: `if let company = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Company.self, key: "ABC") {
                let oldEmployees = company.employees.filter("age = 60")
            }`